# How to "unpublish" a change in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, publish, rollback, solution, undo

If I have made some changes to entities and after publishing them, I decided to rollback these changes. I'm not quite sure which of the solutions currently existing in my CRM is the last update done so that I can publish it and return to my previous state.

Is there a way I can "undo" a publish ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to undo the publish.

If you are not sure about the solution, you can pick any existing unmanaged solution which contains the entity that needs to be rolled back. Then undo the changes manually and publish them. These changes will automatically propagate to all the other unmanaged solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think it would be necessary to include an "undo" in future CRM versions.

Comment: Worst case scenario - restore a backup database.